# How can I migrate a .NET batch job into AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I have a .NET framework 4.6 Windows service that runs a number of batch jobs during the day. These jobs typically involve executing a database query to identify the rows to process, then calling another module to process each row. These jobs can take around an hour to run.

I would like to migrate this code to .NET 6 and host it in AWS. The processing of each item could be moved into an AWS Lambda function. What are my options for moving the other parts, i.e. the scheduling, the database access and the loop to call the lambda?